# D3.js: change bar color AND another svg color on click

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar chart that I'd like to:

1) On click, the selected bar changes color [The code I have works]

2) The circle div changes color based on the bar's height [I can't seem to add that to the code above]

I know

```
.on('click', datum => { console.log(datum); })
```

Will give me the bars height that I want to use for coloring the bar, and that I can use

```
.attr("fill", function (d) { return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d * 10) + ")"; })
```

To change the color of the circle based on the bar height, but I'm struggling to put all these code tidbits together.

```js
              //Width and height
              var w = 500;
              var h = 100;
              var barPadding = 1;

              var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25];

              //Create SVG element
              var svg = d3.select("body")
                     .append("svg")
                     .attr("width", w)
                     .attr("height", h);

              svg.selectAll("rect")
                     .data(dataset)
                     .enter()
                     .append("rect")
                     .attr("class", "allbars")
                     .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                            return i * (w / dataset.length);
                     })
                     .attr("y", function (d) {
                            return h - (d * 4);
                     })
                     .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                     .attr("height", function (d) {
                            return d * 4;
                     })
                     .attr("fill", "#2296F3")
                     /* clicking on the bar gives us the data but how do I use this to change the circle color
                     .on('click', datum => { 
                            console.log(datum); 
                            /* 
                            d3.selectAll('the_circle')
                            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                                   console.log(d)
                                   return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d * 10) + ")";
                            })
                     })
                     /* This code can be used to change the bar color on click */
                     .on("click", function (d) {
                            d3.selectAll('.allbars').style('fill', '#2296F3'); //fill all circles black
                            d3.select(this).style("fill", "#012B4E"); //then fill this circle lightcoral
                     }
                     )


       // Add circle SVG, give it class circle_data that will be effected by on click
       map_svg = d3.select("#the_circle").append("svg")
        .attr("class", "svgWrapper")
       map_svg.append("circle")
       .attr("class", "performer_circle")
       .attr("cx",100)
       .attr("cy", 100)
       .attr("r", 50)
       .attr("fill", "black");
```

```css
       body {
              font-size: 19px;
              font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
              font-weight: 400;
              text-align: center;
       }

       #title {
              font-size: 20px;
              padding-bottom: 10px;
              padding-top: 20px;
              font-weight: 300;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>D3: Adding dynamic color, based on data</title>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

       <div id="bars"></div>
       <div id="the_circle"></div>
       <div id="title">Clicking on a bar changes it's color, it also triggers the circle to change colors</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve, I will leave it to you to manage the color scheme, the thing that you have to manage is the color from [0, 255].

Just add it inside the click event you attached to the bars.

```js
//Width and height
var w = 500;
var h = 100;
var barPadding = 1;

var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25];

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
       .append("svg")
       .attr("width", w)
       .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("class", "allbars")
       .attr("x", function (d, i) {
              return i * (w / dataset.length);
       })
       .attr("y", function (d) {
              return h - (d * 4);
       })
       .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
       .attr("height", function (d) {
              return d * 4;
       })
       .attr("fill", "#2296F3")
       .on("click", function (d) {
           d3.select("#the_circle circle")
           .attr("fill", function () { return "rgb(0, 0, " + Math.round(d * 10) + ")"; });

          d3.selectAll('.allbars').style('fill', '#2296F3');
          d3.select(this).style("fill", "#012B4E");
        }
       )


// Add circle SVG, give it class circle_data that will be effected by on click
map_svg = d3.select("#the_circle").append("svg")
.attr("class", "svgWrapper")
map_svg.append("circle")
.attr("class", "performer_circle")
.attr("cx",100)
.attr("cy", 100)
.attr("r", 50)
.attr("fill", "black");
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>D3: Adding dynamic color, based on data</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
 <div id="bars"></div>
 <div id="the_circle"></div>
 <div id="title">Clicking on a bar changes it's color, it also triggers the circle to change colors</div>
</body>
</html>
```